# Get Selected Object from ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve an object based on the selected item in a List Box doing the following

```
    lstAvailableAppointments.DataTextField = "AppointmentDetails"
    lstAvailableAppointments.DataSource = appointments
    lstAvailableAppointments.DataBind()

    If lstAvailableAppointments.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim appointmentDetails = TryCast(lstAvailableAppointments.SelectedItem, AppointmentHelper)
    End If
```

But im getting an error saying I cant convert the list box item to appointment helper

Comment: Did you try `directcast` instead of `trycast`

Comment: tried didnt work but thanks

Comment: `Dim appointmentDetails as Object = DirectCast(lstAvailableAppointments.SelectedItem, AppointmentHelper)` try this by explicitly declaring an object. May be....

Comment: Are you sure this line is where the code is failing. TryCast shouldn't give an exception, it will just return nothing.

Comment: Also try setting a breakpoint on that line and seeing what type .SelectedItem actually is.

Comment: try `lstAvailableAppointments.SelectedItem.Content` https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx